# Relation between blast wind and overpressure

Tags: waves, aerodynamics, explosions

Suppose we have the ambient air pressure, density, speed of sound and blast overpressure. How can we use this data to get the speed of the blast wind?

Currently I simply assume that 50% of the wave's energy is kinetic, an assumption that worked for water waves, so dynamic pressure = overpressure. How right is this?

Comment: Have you heard of the Sedov blast wave or of self-similar solutions?

Comment: @KyleKanos I checjed it out but I want something that works when overpressure is comparable to ambient pressure

Comment: Well I suppose it wouldn't be much of a "blast" if the pressures are comparable, but the Sedov solution could still be used to give you an approximation (though probably a weak approximation at that).

Comment: @KyleKanos I am trying to prove that long period blast waves can cause the same damage for a much lower overpressure.

Comment: So you want to distribute the same total energy but (effectively) have one scenario be a driven process instead of a single release of energy? Seems to me that you might have to run some simulations to test that; any 1D hydro code ought to suffice for testing.